# WCF Web Service "POST [OperationContract]" returns "Endpoint not found", when published on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis

I have created a WCF Web Service. Which have some [OperationContract] with GET request and one [OperationContract] with POST request. The problem is that, the POST [OperationContract] works fine with localhost but when published on IIS it returns "Endpoint not found" error.

Here is my WCF Service Interface

**Interface IService1.cs**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UploadImage", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    string UploadImage(Stream stream);
```

OR (Alternatively)

When I call this POST [OperationContract] with this URL: http://localhost:5031/Service1.svc/UploadImage , Then it works fine.

BUT

when I call it with URL: http://IP/Wcfservice1/Service1.svc/UploadImage , Then it returns "Endpoint not found"

---

Here is my Interface Implementation:

**IService1.svc.cs**

```
   public class Service : IService
    {
         public string UploadImage(Stream stream)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int index = r.Next(0, 99);

            System.Drawing.Bitmap imag = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(stream);
            byte[] imagedata = ImageToByte(imag);
            //Write code here to Save byte code to database..  

            stream.Read(imagedata, 0, imagedata.Length);
            FileStream f = new FileStream(@"E:\Studies\Uploaded Images\TestProfileImage" + index + ".jpg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            f.Write(imagedata, 0, imagedata.Length);
            f.Close();
            stream.Close();
            return "Success";
        }
    }

 public static byte[] ImageToByte(System.Drawing.Image img)
        {

            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
```

### }

and in my web.config I have the following:

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
           <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WcfService1.WebHttp" maxBufferSize="2147483647"

                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"

                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"

                 transferMode="Streamed"

                 sendTimeout="00:05:00">
          <readerQuotas  maxDepth="2147483647"

                         maxStringContentLength="2147483647"

                         maxArrayLength="2147483647"

                         maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"

                         maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="myweb" contract="WcfService1.IService1" binding="webHttpBinding" />
      <host>
       <baseAddresses>
           <add baseAddress="http://localhost:5031/Service1.svc" />
       </baseAddresses>
</host>
      </service>

    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name ="myweb">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" /> 
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
   <security>

                                <requestFiltering>

                                               <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="102400000" />

                                </requestFiltering>

                </security>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Please let me know, what's the problem here and what do i need to fix. 
Thanks you for taking time to have a look on this post.
**Thanks**

Comment: I don't think this is POST/GET operation issue. It is more of a routing issue.

Comment: How have you configured your application in IIS? The version that works seems to be run from VS. What is the app path from your root in IIS?

Comment: @RossBush what should i do then ?

Comment: @RossBush , No i didn't configured my application in IIS? Can you please guide me on that?

Comment: You have to know your web root right, normally the IP. and from  that you branch off and make applications. You say that you published,can you post the url or location that you published to?

Comment: @RossBush , I don't exactly know what are you talking about, as I am a beginner. And by "publishing"  I mean that I have hosted this service in IIS on my local computer by creating a Virtual Directory, but I am trying to access it on the other computer. All the GET operations are working well with that IP url but POST are not working ?

Answer (score 0):

http://192.168.1.5/Service1.svc/UploadImage .

instead of http://192.168.1.5/Wcfservice1/Service1.svc/UploadImage 
 hopefully it might work.

Comment: I think the swebsite is not hosted properly. Have you publish your website proprly?

Answer (score 0):

would you please remove the host section from your config file and try this http://IP/Wcfservice1/Service1.svc/UploadImage again?
UPDATE:

try to enable the service help page. then we can find out the endpoint adress. add this section to tour config:

```
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myweb">
            <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultBodyStyle="Bare" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
```

Comment: I removed the host section and then tried again but the error "Endpoint not found" is still there..?

Comment: Ok. do you know how enable the service help page? its simple. i edited my answer. enable the help page and see what is your endpoint address.

Comment: I enabled the help page following your instructions.    And Here is the help page of my service...  Operations at http://localhost:5031/Service1.svc

This page describes the service operations at this endpoint.

Uri Method Description
get GET Service at http://localhost:5031/Service1.svc/get
UpdateUserDetail POST Service at http://localhost:5031/Service1.svc/UpdateUserDetail
UploadImage POST Service at http://localhost:5031/Service1.svc/UploadImage

Comment: i guess its pretty clear now dear @Naveed. your application is not available at the 192.168.1.5 host. are you sure you config the application to use the iis? did you create new web site in your iis?

Comment: Yes @David, thanks for your help. You are right, it was not available there. I added it again & configured it again. Now everything is working fine... Thanks

Comment: glad i could help.